# USB-MIDI driver on Windows 10

Tags: windows, usb, driver, midi

I would like to develop a piece of HW that will transform my breath into MIDI messages to drive a sample library. The HW should be connected to the PC where the library is running via USB.

My problem is that once I have this HW and the firmware developed properly how can I make Windows 10 able to recognize the device as a MIDI controller to connect it to the sample library?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 (and all previous versions since Me/XP) recognize devices that conform to the [USB MIDI device class specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/).